# Using ref instead of out. Would that be considered a bug?

Tags: c#, methods

Given that out and ref parameters have slight different connotations would writing code like below be considered a bug (even though it doesn't cause an issue at present), or just a lack of understanding on ref and out parameters?

```
public void MyMethod() 
{
    int myInt = 0;
    MyMethodWithRef(ref myInt);
}

public void MyMethodWithRef(ref myInt)
{
    // not used before being assigned a value.  Does an out parameter make more sense then  
    myInt = 5;
}
```

I understand that this is the incorrect usage of ref but if you saw that in code constantly or even once would you consider it a bug and hence fix it as well as inform the original coder or just do it as part of general refactoring practices?

Comment: Just nitpicking a little, but "a bug" means incorrect behavior. If `ref` and `out` have the same semantics in this case, then it can't be a bug, by definition. It might by *stylistically incorrect,* though.

Comment: It's a _design bug_.  The **strong** implication of `ref` is that the input value in `myInt` is not ignored.

Comment: @MasonWheeler no problem with the nitpick.  This is the thing I'm asking.  Could it be described as incorrect behaviour from a programmers point of view though, not a clients?  Does bug depend on the context of the user looking at it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug in that the compiler won't flag it and given the existing code base, it will not cause a difference in behavior.

It is an issue that would be brought up in a code review or interview -- it is imprecise, it makes the next programmer ask "why", which if not a mortal sin is at least a venial sin. Is it left over from a copy/paste code reuse, a half implemented feature, part of an incomplete bug fix -- which way, changing from out to ref or vice-a-versa, is it necessary and I'm just not seeing it, is it a terrible mistake by someone that didn't know better and am I not seeing that....

Although I generally approve of extra restrictions, I'm not convinced that in practice this is a useful syntax -- that said, the language does make the distinction, and there's a cost to not following conventions.  Not in terms of performance or scale, but in readability and maintainability.

Comment: Having worked on a code base where one programmer used ref parameters for all mutable objects, it may be an indication that someone needs to learn about how parameter passing works in C#.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: I worked on a VB.NET project where that exact mistake was made -- I started to fix it, realized it was everywhere and I needed to talk to the other devs before making such a massive change (both to make sure that everyone knew how it worked and to make sure that it wasn't being used as a convention even though it was wrong). Life happened and I left before having a chance to have that conversation.

Answer (score 10):

From the C# documentation.

> An argument that is passed to a **ref** parameter must be initialized before it is passed. This differs from **out** parameters, whose arguments do not have to be explicitly initialized before they are passed
>
> The **out** keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is similar to the **ref** keyword, except that **ref** requires that the variable be initialized before being passed.
>
> The **ref** and **out** keywords are treated differently at run-time, but they are treated the same at compile time.

I think that explains it well.

If you **need** the method to be passed a value, then use **ref**. If you need the method to just output a value, then use **out**.  You shouldn't use **out** if you expect the parameter of the method to contain a value already.

Your example is not a bug, because the compiler imposes this restriction. A **ref** can output a result. That is not it's requirement. The requirement is that it has been initialized.

It would be a bug if you expected **out** to already contain a value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an out makes more sense in that case. It will be more readable as to intent.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, I would change your return type from `void` to `int`, declare `myInt` local to the method, then `return` it at the end.

Comment: More giving it as an example or if you saw this type of thing rather than it is exactly what I saw.  Your right with your comment though.  I would even give it a better name than MyMethodWithRef :)